# using grease pencil with transparent object

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil

I'm trying to use grease pencil on two objects, but one object is inside the other. I still want to see grease pencil on the inside object.

I have a blue cube inside a green cube. The green cube is transparent, and I want both cubes to have an outline (using grease pencil).

Is this possible??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi  Austyn. It is possible to see a Grease Pencil object under a transparent Object material but only if using Eeevee render engine. Try switching to Eevee and see if that resolves the issue. Make sure in the Settings of the transparent material to set Blend Mode to Alpha Blend.

Comment: @RumenBelev I changed to Eevee render and made sure my blend mode was Alpha, but it still isnt showing. I added a photo to the post as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are Using **Line Art** modifier on a Grease Pencil objects.
This modifier works using **Camera View** but doesn't generate hidden edges.

You can try the following:

Make sure to switch to **Eeeve** render engine.

Add **Cube** with semi-transparent material.
In the material settings set the **Blend Mode** to **Alpha Blend**
Duplicate the Cube and Convert it to Grease Pencil (Right Click menu). Go in the material settings of the generated **Grease Pencil** and delete the White material responsible for the fill color.

Add another cube and scale it down. **Do not** activate **Alpha Blend** in its material settings. Duplicate the cube and convert to Grease Pencil. Repeat the process with the GP material leaving only the outline.

The result should be like this:

[image]